Doubts about the divergence of $\sum_n\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$
Let $$y_n:=\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}.$$
The series $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n$$
diverges by using the limit comparison test with $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}}$, but I seem to prove that it is convergent by using the ratio test. What is wrong in the following calculation?
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n)^n(2n+3)^{n+1}}\sqrt \frac{2n+1}{2n+3}=$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n}\left(1-\frac{2}{2n+3}\right)^{n+1}=$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(1-\frac{2}{2n+3}\right)^{\frac{2n+3}{-2}}\right)^{\frac{-2(n+1)}{2n+3}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-1}=e^{\frac{-1}{2}}<1$$

What does LCT mean?

@Steen82 Limit Comparison Test

$$\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} \ne  \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n)^n(2n+3)^{n+1}}\sqrt \frac{2n+1}{2n+3}$$
because
$$y_{n} = \left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}} \Rightarrow y_{n+1} = \left(\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}\right)^{n+1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+3}}$$
and there's no term $(2n+2)^{n+1}$ in what you written.

silly mistake... Thank you again, I've checked for a long time.

@Morten You are welcome!

As an alternative we can also use the simpler direct comparison test
$$\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\ge \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+2n}}=\frac14\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$$

The ratio test is simple $$y_n=\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$$
$$\log(y_n)=n \log(2n)-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2 n+1)$$
Write
$$\log(y_{n+1})-\log(y_n)= ???$$
Use Taylor series for large $n$
$$\log(y_{n+1})-\log(y_n)=-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{3}{8n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor since
$$\frac{ y_{n+1}} { y_{n}}=e^{\log(y_{n+1})-\log(y_n) }=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
Bonus
If you wish to approximate the partial sum
$$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$$ use the series expansion of $\log(y_n)$ and re-exponentiate
$$y_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 e n} }\left(1-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{11}{384 n^2}-\frac{25}{3072 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \right)$$ Forget the higher order terms and sum termwise to obtain a linear combination of generalized harmonic numbers since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac 1 {n^{k+\frac{1}{2}} }=H_m^{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
Using their asymptotics and obtain
$$S_m \sim C+\sqrt{\frac{2m}{e}}\left(1+\frac{3}{8 m}-\frac{71}{1152 m^2} +\cdots\right)$$ where $C\sim -\frac 34$.
If you use $m=100$, the above would give  $7.85975$ while the exact summation gives $7.85682$.
